# C++ Sytanx about Array of Class and usage of new operator

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-keyword

My question is about a code snanpshot from Scott Meyer's Book "More Effective C++ 35 new ways ..."

the code (parameter names are changed)

```
void * memory = operator new[] (10*sizeOf(MyClass));
MyClass * myArray = static_cast<MyClass*>(memory);
for(int i= 0; i<10; i++)
{
new (&myArray[i]) MyClass(params);
}
```

I am not familiar with this syntax. Even the operator new [] and the new (&myArray[i]) ... Is there any resource that I can read detailed about that syntax, how they are working.

Comment: it is allocating `memory` for `10` `MyClass` and then storing `10` `MyClass` in it

Comment: actually i know what this code is coding :) but i try to understand to learn the syntax about "operator new[]" and the last row : " new (&myArray[i] MyClass(params) " ... maybe i have to check the assemble but i would to complicated. i want to understand the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this, you first need to understand how plain and simple `new` works. The usual syntax of a `new` expression is something like `new T`. When you use a `new` expression, the following occurs:

1. First, it calls an *allocation function* to obtain storage for the object. The allocation function simply has to return a pointer to some allocated storage large enough to fit the requested object. It does no more than this. It doesn't initialize the object.
2. Next, the object is initialized in the allocated space.
3. A pointer to the allocated space (and now initialized object) is returned.

In the case of `new T`, the allocation function is named `operator new`. When allocating an array, such as `new T[5]`, the allocation function is named `operator new[]`. Default definitions of these functions are provided in the global namespace. They each take a single argument of type `std::size_t` which is the number of bytes required. So when you do `new T`, the corresponding call is to `operator new(sizeof(T))`, whereas for `new T[5]`, `operator new[](sizeof(T)*5)` gets called.

It is, however, possible to pass more arguments to the allocation function. This is known as the *placement new* syntax. To pass more arguments, you use syntax like so: `new (some, arguments, 3) T`, which will call `operator new(sizeof(T), some, arguments, 3)`. The list of arguments goes in parentheses between `new` and the type.

In addition to the simple `operator new(std::size_t)` and its array counterpart that are both provided by the implementation, there are also default definitions that take an extra argument of type `void*`. That is, they take a pointer to an object. These functions don't actually allocate any space and simply return the pointer you gave them. So when you do `new (some_pointer) T`, it first calls `operator new(sizeof(T), some_pointer)` which just returns `some_pointer` back again and then it initializes the object in that space. This gives you a way to initialize an object in some *already allocated* space.

So now we have these four pre-defined allocation functions (in fact, there are a few others and you're free to define your own too):

```
// Normal allocation functions that allocate space of the given size
operator new(std::size_t)
operator new[](std::size_t)
// Placement allocation functions that just return the pointer they're given
operator new(std::size_t, void*)
operator new[](std::size_t, void*)
```

---

So lets take a look at the code snippet you provided:

```
void * memory = operator new[] (10*sizeOf(MyClass));
MyClass * myArray = static_cast<MyClass*>(memory);
for(int i= 0; i<10; i++)
{
  new (&myArray[i]) MyClass(params);
}
```

In the first line, we are calling `operator new[]` directly to allocate some storage. How much storage? Well, enough for 10 objects of type `MyClass`. This function returns a pointer to that allocated storage and you store it in `memory`.

After this, the `void*` is cast to a `MyClass*` to allow you to index the allocated storage in blocks of size `sizeof(MyClass)`, i.e. `myArray[0]` will now point to the first `MyClass`  and `myArray[1]` to the second.

Now we loop through that array, calling *placement new* with the address of each uninitialized `MyClass`-sized bit of allocated storage. In the first iteration, for example, this will call allocation function `operator new(sizeof(MyClass), &myArray[0])` which, as we saw before, does nothing but return the pointer you've given it. The new expression will complete by initializing a `MyClass` object in this space and returning the pointer to it.

So in summary, the code allocates some storage to fit 10 `MyClass` objects (but doesn't initialize them), then loops through each `MyClass`-sized space in that storage, initializing an object in each of them.

This demonstrates how you can initialize objects in already pre-allocated storage. You can reuse the same storage over and over with newly initialized objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
void * memory = operator new[] (10*sizeOf(MyClass));
```

Here you allocate memory of size `10*sizeOf(MyClass)` bytes. This is raw *uninitialized* memory. There is no C++ objects constructed in this memory.

```
new (&myArray[i]) MyClass(params);
```

Here you use *placement-new* to construct an object in the given memory pointed to by `&myArray[i]`.

The typical syntax for placement-new is this:

```
X * x = new (pAllocatedMem) X(a,b,c);
```

It means, you construct an object of type `X` passing `a`,`b`,`c` to the constructor. The object is constructed at memory pointed  to by `pAllocatedMem`.

Also note that you delete such object which is constructed using placement-new, as:

```
x->~X(); //delete the constructed object. DONT USE : delete x;
```

That is, you don't do `delete x` to delete such objects.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia will answer your questions.

The first `new` is for allocating raw memory.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)#void.2A_operator_new.28size_t_size.29

> The C++ language construct that only allocates memory is called void* operator new(size_t size). It is used by new in the allocation phase. It can be overridden per class to define a class specific memory allocator.

---

The second `new` is called placement new.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_new

> The placement overloads of operator new and operator delete that employ an additional void * parameter are used for default placement, also known as pointer placement.

Answer (score 1):

```
new (&myArray[i]) MyClass(params);
```

is the **Placement `new`** operator. It allows you to create an object at pre-allocated memory location.

**18.4.1.3 Placement forms**

> void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw();
>
> Returns: ptr.
> 3 Notes: Intentionally performs no other action.
> 4 [Example: This can be useful for constructing an object at a known address:

```
void* place = operator new(sizeof(Something));

Something* p = new (place) Something();
—end example]

void* operator new[](std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw();

5 Returns: ptr.
6 Notes: Intentionally performs no other action.
```